# Select from a dropdown list of users to assign them to a certain Room

Tags: python, django, database, model

I'm trying to create a dropdown list of users that can be changed and updated if the admin user desires. I am able to see the dropdown list of users but when I go to create the Room and try to select a user, it doesn't get saved and that field remains blank. I used a `ModelChoiceField` in my `forms.py` file to create the dropdown list of users. I think its because I didn't call it correctly in the `views.py` but I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help is much appreciated

Here is my code so far

forms.py

```
class RoomForm(ModelForm):
    userList = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    
    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['host', 'participants']
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def createRoom(request):
    form = RoomForm()
    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        topic_name = request.POST.get('topic')
        topic, created = Topic.objects.get_or_create(name=topic_name)

        Room.objects.create(
            host=request.user,
            topic=topic,
            userList = request.POST.get('userList'),
            name=request.POST.get('name'),
            status=request.POST.get('status'),
            priority=request.POST.get('priority'),
            type=request.POST.get('type'),
            description=request.POST.get('description'),
        )
        return redirect('home')

    context = {'form': form, 'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'room/room_form.html', context)


@login_required(login_url='login')
def updateRoom(request, pk):
    room = Room.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = RoomForm(instance=room)
    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    if request.user != room.host:
        return HttpResponse('You are not allowed here!!')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        topic_name = request.POST.get('topic')
        topic, created = Topic.objects.get_or_create(name=topic_name)
        room.name = request.POST.get('name')
        room.topic = topic
        room.user = room.user
        room.status = request.POST.get('status')
        room.priority = request.POST.get('priority')
        room.type = request.POST.get('type')
        room.description = request.POST.get('description')
        room.save()
        return redirect('room', pk=room.id)

    context = {'form': form, 'topics': topics, 'room': room}
    return render(request, 'room/room_form.html', context)
```

part of Room models.py

```
class Room(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.BooleanField(choices=STATUS, default=True)
    priority = models.TextField(choices=PRIORITIES, default='None', max_length=10)
    type = models.TextField(choices=TYPE, default='Misc', max_length=15)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name='participants', blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issuetracker\base\views.py", line 57, in createRoom
    Room.objects.create(
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 512, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 559, in __init__
    raise TypeError(

Exception Type: TypeError at /create-room/
Exception Value: Room() got an unexpected keyword argument 'userList'
```

Comment: You have no field as `UserList` in the model, also if you have created ModelForm, so why you are not using Django form?

Comment: The host is the head of the room.  The participants are the people in the room.  Can you explain what the difference is between the participants and the users in the userList?